# what is the best way to use vue, vue-router to make a dashboard with keep-alive?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vue-router, vuex

I'm using vue2, vue-router with keep-alive to develop a dashboard. What I want to achieve is following:

1. page should re-fetch when login -> logout -> login other account 
   (use beforeRouterEnter, beforeRouterLeave to re-fetch !? or use condition to keep alive component or not !?)

but vue-router can't use vue data to check page should keep alive or not...

2. in HTML template, it will render and render. If there has some vuex data show directly in HTML, it will error with not have the object inside object yet ex:

> user: {
>       plan: {
>         xxx: ''
>       }
>     }

sure I can give vuex data all of property init data. It can avoid this thing happen, but if the page with keep alive, it still happens...

also, I can write many v-if in the template, but I think it's not a good idea to put v-if all around the template to make sure data exist..ex:
v-if="user.plan && user.plan.xxx"
or add v-if in component root template, is that a good idea !?

use beforeMount without keeping alive, there is no problem but it's not a good user experience dashboard (when you change page, data disappear or you have already load page data but load again)

Is there anyone who really use Vue 2 and it's relative library (vuex, vue-router) to develop can tell me how you develop your SPA project !?

Comment: vue-router can't use vuex data, but the component can. Instead of using navigation guards, make the login button call an action that, when the API call is successful, calls the router to go to another route (you can import the router instance in your actions).

Comment: It's what I doing now! I think there will face no problem with SPA website, but if it's a little complex SPA dashboard system, there is what I facing.. I also use a variable like appReady to route-view to make sure my page has vuex. But there still have some problem as I mention..QQ

Comment: by the way, without keep-alive, everythings work..but I want keep-alive!! @@

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are doing to logout is the following: press button => go to login screen => use beforeRouteEnter to delete data. And you are using a different guard to login. I would suggest to do the following: press button => call action => action calls mutation when data is fetched, and then calls router.push().